# Pytest "run-around-tests" fixture to run only once before all tests in a class

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, pytest

I am testing the User message function of a web solution using pytest + selenium. The tests will generate a test message to a test user, and then log in that user to verify that the message indeed is displaying for that user.

- I need to generate those messages through an internal API.
- In order to be able to access this API, I first have to generate an AUTH token through a different API.

So the test scenario is basically:

1. At test startup, generate a new AUTH token through an API helper function.
2. Send a request to another API to set a new message (requires the AUTH token)
3. Send a request to yet another API to "map" this message to a specified user (requires the AUTH token)
4. Log in test user and verify that the new message is indeed displaying.

My problem is that I want to avoid creating a new AUTH token every time every test within my test class is run - I want to create a new token once that all tests use within the same test run.

What is the smartest solution to generate one new access token when invoking all tests?

Right now I have come up with something like this, which will generate a new token every time any individual test is run:

```
import pytest
import helpers.api_access_token_helper as token_helper
import helpers.user_message_generator_api_helper as message_helper
import helpers.login_helper as login_helper
import helpers.popup_helper as popup_helper

class TestStuff(object):

    @pytest.yield_fixture(autouse=True)
    def run_around_tests(self):
        yield token_helper.get_api_access_token()

    def test_one(self, run_around_tests):
        auth_token = run_around_tests
        message_helper.create_new_message(auth_token, some_message_data)
        message_helper.map_message_to_user(auth_token, user_one["user_id"])
        login_helper.log_in_user(user_one["user_name"], user_one["user_password"])
        assert popup_helper.user_message_is_displaying(some_message_data["title"])

    def test_two(self, run_around_tests):
        auth_token = run_around_tests
        message_helper.create_new_message(auth_token, some_other_message_data)
        message_helper.map_message_to_user(auth_token, user_two["user_id"])
        login_helper.log_in_user(user_two["user_name"], user_two["user_password"])
        assert popup_helper.user_message_is_displaying(some_other_message_data["title"])
```

I have laborated back and forth a bit with the "run-around-tests" fixture but havent been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to adapt the fixture scope to cache its results for all tests in test run (`scope='session'`), all tests in module (`scope='module'`), all tests in class (old `unittest`-style tests only, `scope='class'`), or for a single test (`scope='function'`; this the default one). Examples:

#### fixture function

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def token():
    return token_helper.get_api_access_token()


class Tests(object):

    def test_one(self, token):
        ...

    def test_two(self, token):
        ...


class OtherTests(object):

    def test_one(self, token):
        ...
```

The token will be calculated once when first requested and kept in cache throughout the whole test run, so all three tests `Tests::test_one`, `Tests::test_two` and `OtherTests::test_one` will share the same token value.

#### fixture class method

If you intend to write old-style test classes instead of test functions and want the fixture to be a class method (like it is in your code), note that you can only use the `class` scope, so that the fixture value is shared only between the tests in the class:

```
class TestStuff(object):

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def token(self):
        return token_helper.get_api_access_token()

    def test_one(self, token):
        ...

    def test_two(self, token):
        ...
```

Stuff aside:

1. `pytest.yield_fixture` is deprecated and replaced by `pytest.fixture`;
2. you don't need to set `autouse=True` because you explicitly request the fixture in the test parameters. It will be called anyway.

Comment: Yep that did the trick. Should have laborated a bit more with the fixture... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a scope="module" parameter to the @pytest.fixture.

According to [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session):

> Fixtures requiring network access depend on connectivity and are
> usually time-expensive to create. Extending the previous example, we
> can add a scope="module" parameter to the @pytest.fixture invocation
> to cause a smtp_connection fixture function, responsible to create a
> connection to a preexisting SMTP server, to only be invoked once per
> test module (the default is to invoke once per test function).
> Multiple test functions in a test module will thus each receive the
> same smtp_connection fixture instance, thus saving time. Possible
> values for scope are: function, class, module, package or session.

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest
import smtplib


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def smtp_connection():
    return smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=5)
```

#### Fixture scopes

Fixtures are created when first requested by a test, and are destroyed based on their scope:*

`function`: the default scope, the fixture is destroyed at the end of the test.

`class`: the fixture is destroyed during teardown of the last test in the class.

`module`: the fixture is destroyed during teardown of the last test in the module.

`package`: the fixture is destroyed during teardown of the last test in the package.

`session`: the fixture is destroyed at the end of the test session.

##### Note: *Pytest only caches one instance of a fixture at a time, which means that when using a parametrized fixture, pytest may invoke a fixture more than once in the given scope.*